# Is ssl necessary for apns?

Tags: iphone, ssl, apple-push-notifications

Is ssl necessary for Apple's Push Notification Service (apns)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL is the only solution to send notifications !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, But not in the usual sense of buying an SSL to sit on a server for a website. The SSL is generated from the certificate you acquire when registering with apple for the iOS developer scheme.

There is a fantastic tutorial on getting an APNS provider server up and running here:

[How to build an Apple Push Notification provider server (tutorial) by David Mytton](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is required, otherwise it would be insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Not only that it is necessary, it is mandatory. And furthermore, you should consider using TLS instead of SSL.